# Trouble with firebase and Picasso Storage

Tags: android, firebase, picasso

My Upload Code :

```
package com.example.mfapp;

public class Upload {
    private String mName;
    private String mImageUrl;

    public Upload() {

    }

    public Upload(String name, String imageUrl) {
        if (name.trim().equals("")) {
            name = "No Name";
        }
        mName = name;
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }




    public void getImageUrl(String ImageUrl) {
        mImageUrl = ImageUrl;

    }
}
```

My ImageAdapter :

```
    package com.example.mfapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Upload> mUploads;
public  ImageAdapter(Context context,List<Upload> uploads){
    mContext = context;
    mUploads = uploads;
}


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item,parent,false);
       return  new ImageViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());

        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl()).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUploads.size();
    }

    public  class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView textViewName;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_upload);
        }
    }

}
```

Error in this string :

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl()).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);
```

It is my error in 39 string.
D:\MFAPP\app\src\main\java\com\example\mfapp\ImageAdapter.java:39: error: method getImageUrl in class Upload cannot be applied to given types;
.load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl()).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);
^
required: String
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Please help me.

Comment: You could reformat the error message towards the bottom of your post so that it was more readable, and by doing so you might see the answer. I'm no Java or Picasso expert, but I think the error message is telling you that the `getImageUrl` method is defined as taking a single parameter of type `String`, and currently you're using `.load(uploadCurrent.getImageURL())` (no parameter being passed.